# Badge Suggestion: "Late to the Party"

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Awarded to someone who receives the green check after it has already been awarded to someone else (iff the new answer was posted after the green check, perhaps?).  Alternative name: '1 Upper' (for 1-upping the previous answer).

Might provide incentive for encouraging more thoughtful/detailed responses to questions that you feel is currently shortchanged by the answers.

Comment: I like it, but what happens if the OP starts changing his accepted answer randomly?. I don't see how something like this can be easily implemented and not gamed.

Comment: I would suggest then the badge is only awarded once the green check has been frozen.

Comment: This seems a lot like Necromancer. A little better because it's about acceptance, but inferior because the OP may no longer be around to award the checkmark.

Comment: Could you define "frozen"?

Comment: It's been a while, but once I went back and reviewed new material/answers to a question, went to adjust the green check, only to be denied due to the age of the question/accepted answer

Comment: That's odd. I was sure, until you said that, that that never happened. Was it a question you awarded a bounty on, before the bounty system changed?

Comment: @Matt: What you're describing sounds like a _bug_. By design, you should always be able to unaccept. (Not exactly sure about bounties here, but even there I would be surprised.)

Comment: I like this, but it would be trivial to game with sock puppets. In fact, once implemented, we'd probably have an _easier_ time finding them. What to do ... what to do ...

Answer (score 14):

It just happened to me a few minutes ago.

I had submitted a question to EL&U for which I only reluctantly accepted an answer weeks ago.  Only to find out today that somebody else had come up with a nearly perfect answer.
Of course I shifted the green tick to the better answer, but I also felt that that was a small reward for the effort of digging up the question from the bottom of the stack and providing an enlightening answer.

May be the condition could be that the question's originally accepted answer must have been accepted more than NN days before the shift in order to avoid people fiddling with the conditions.  That would add some viscosity to the system.  There should be a numerical threshold anyway.

**Edit**
As I was answering Gilles comment, it also occurred to me that a badge to earn would have the positive side effect that people would be more willing to browse through older questions to see if they have a genuinely better answer to propose.

Overall this would

- Unearth old questions => less duplicates.
- Increase the quality of the pool of answers for existing questions because a good answer to a tricky question ultimately depends on whether a person knowing the answer comes in contact with the question.
- Improve the quality of the site because accepted answers would have more chance to have been reviewed even once accepted.

Comment: If you think the answer is awesome and would like to reward it more, there are a couple of things you can do. You can award a bounty to it (you'll have to wait 24 hours between setting the bounty and awarding it; I think it's only polite to put a temporary comment on the question indicating that you already have a target in mind for the bounty). You can browse the answerer's questions and see if you can reciprocate.

Comment: @Gilles.  You're perfectly right. As it happens, I've actually done all three things.  Comment of course.  A few weeks ago I awarded a 50 rep bounty to another answer from that same person. and I have found some nice answers which could do with a genuinely deserved up-vote.  I nevertheless wish to second the *official* mean of a badge put forward by the OP.  Also see my edition .

Comment: There's already [Revival](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/126/revival) and [Necromancer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) for unearthing old questions, and in a different vein [Populist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/37/populist) for outscoring an accepted answer. That does leave room for a badge for providing a better-than-originally-accepted answer if the new answer is accepted. There definitely should be a long enough interval between the initial acceptance and the new answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this will happen. This would be too easily acquirable, making it bronze badge, and we have enough of those.

By the way, "better answer than accepted answer" is already rewarded by reputation.

#### Edit

The `Populist` badge `Answer outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x` does something like this.